# how to disable autofs4

Tags: autofs

this line is from the output of `dmesg -e` on Ubuntu 15.04 using `systemd` and UEFI:

```
[ +14.874691] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
```

as it shows it takes 14 seconds to load. To my knowledge, `autofs4` is used to auto-mount partitions on start-up, please correct me if I am wrong. I don't need any partition mounted on start-up.
 The question is, is it safe to disable `autofs4` ? if yes how can I do that?

**UPDATE**: the above output comes from `dmesg -e` but if I try only `dmesg` then I get this:

```
[    6.883649] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   21.495107] systemd[1]: Module 'autofs4' is blacklisted
```

as you can see that system has to wait for 14 seconds before `autofs4` is loaded

Comment: Are you sure that that isn't a timestamp, telling you that at (only) 14 seconds into the boot process `systemd` loaded the `autofs4` module?

Comment: I am sure that `+` sign shows it takes that amount of time to load that module

Comment: What if disabling service ?

Comment: it is a module, are you sure we can disable it just like server? btw i tried `systemct disable autofs` its gets executed successfully without any ouput

Comment: Now service should be disabled, try rebooting.

Comment: according to my knowledge, if you disable service systemd will show you output that removed symlink from systemd folder, which in my case did not happen

Comment: it is not mandatory. I've just tried on opensuse, it did not output anything.

Comment: You're only looking at kernel logs here, that doesn't tell you much about what systemd is doing. It's likely that whatever attempts to load the `autofs4` module does so at around 21.49, you need to look at systemd's logs (I don't know where they are) to see what else is happening before that time.

Comment: @Gilles output of `dmesg` is [here](http://sprunge.us/JZZi) if you will see, you can notice that there is a wait before loading `autofs4` and other timestamps one after the other are quite continious

Comment: Again, and for the last time: 1. You are only looking at the kernel logs, this does not tell you what happens elsewhere. 2. This does not indicate that `autofs4` is the one taking time, it could be somethnig that happens before and does not generate a kernel log. The fact that loading autofs4 or not makes no difference is a strong indicator that autofs4 has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't myself checked that out, but you should be able to blacklist the autofs4 module.

That means you should add

```
blacklist autofs4
```

into a modprobe config file, e.g. into a new file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-autofs4.conf`.

I found this thread https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-June/152585.html that suggests blacklisting that module.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and fast response, can you please dig up more and be sure with your answer?

Comment: the real purpose was to reduce boot time but it didnt worked, see this `[ +15.197452] systemd[1]: Module 'autofs4' is blacklisted` it still takes 15 seconds on boot. can help me out with this?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Sorry, no idea. Are you sure this takes 15 seconds?

Comment: yes i am sure :-)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds How do you know that it's autofs that's taking 15 seconds, and not something happening just before or just after?

Comment: @Gilles I am using this command `dmesg -e` which gives output which has this `[ +14.874691] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'` as one of the lines

Comment: @Gilles you can see my update in question